# Catch error when analysis services refresh fail through webhook ADF

Tags: webhooks, azure-analysis-services, azure-runbook

I have a runbook that is called multiple times from ADF but with different parameters. What it does is that it just refresh different analysis services.
I use the web activity in ADF

[image]

With POST method and in the Body i state which analysis service i want to refresh.
Here is the code for the runbook:
[image]

The runbook says that all jobs is completed
[image]

But one of them have actually failed:
[image]

Does anyone know how i can catch this error?
Now i have no way of knowing that this has failed, except for going in to every job and look in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know how i can catch this error? Now i have no way of knowing that this has failed, except for going in to every job and look in details.

- Yes, this is the way of using Azure Automation Accounts.
- Here Job completion means executing the PowerShell code, but it doesn't means you are getting desired output.(PowerShell commands gives errors, outputs, etc)

[image]

- This is a limitation in Automation Accounts, you need to go inside job to get to know about the status of job.

Alternatively,There is another way to get to know the errors using Inbuilt queries in Logs Section Of Automation Account.

[image]

You can use below query which I have taken from [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-manage-send-joblogs-log-analytics#list-all-runbooks--jobs-that-completed-successfully-with-errors):

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.AUTOMATION" and Category == "JobStreams" and StreamType_s == "Error" 
| project TimeGenerated , RunbookName_s , StreamType_s , _ResourceId , ResultDescription , JobId_g
```

**Error is in Result description:**

[image]

Note( to get logs of jobs you need to enable logging and tracing in inside the runbook):

[image]